# Get time in a fixed timezone in PowerShell Cross-Platform

Tags: powershell

I want the time in Central European Standard Time (CET) in `HH:mm` format. The following works fine on a computer with CET set:

```bsh
Get-Date -f HH:mm
15:55
```

However, on a machine with GMT it returns `13:55`.

The following works on some Windows machines:

```bsh
Get-Date ([System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId((Get-Date), 'Central Europe Standard Time')) -f HH:mm
15:55
```

However, Linux (pwsh/PowerShell Core) machines do not know `Central Europe Standard Time` but instead something like `Europe/Zurich`. I don't like this long string instead of a simple `CET` code anyway so is there a better way to convert to a known timezone?

Comment: can you use UTC and the local time zone offset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately:

- No, **there is no *shorter* way to identify a time zone**, because the examples you give are indeed the `.Id` property values of [`System.TimeZoneInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.TimeZoneInfo) instances.

  - While you could use a [`System.DateTimeOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTimeOffset) instance
- No, **there is no *cross-platform* way to identify a time zone**, because the **built-in time zones differ between Windows and Unix-like platforms not only in terms of *identifiers* (`.Id`), but also in *geographic granularity* and *historical scope***:

  - For instance, what is expressed by single time zone `Eastern Standard Time` (US & Canada) on *Windows* (based on information in the *registry*), is expressed as *multiple* time zones on *Unix*-like platforms (macOS and Linux, based on the [ICU library](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/datetime/timezone/)), such as `America/New_York`, `America/Toronto` and many more.
  - These more granular time zones on Unix aren't just different names for the same thing, they carry specific *historical* information, so converting a historical date based may *differ* between `America/New_York` and `America/Toronto`, for instance, even though *today* they correspond to the same time zone.

---

The above implies that **if you want to guarantee the same behavior across platforms in *all* cases**, even more work is needed, because you then mustn't rely on the built-in time zones and instead **use serialized time-zone *definitions***, which you can derive from a built-in time zone on *one* platform.

The following example shows how to use a serialized time-zone definition obtained from the `Central Europe Standard Time` time zone *on Windows* via [`System.TimeZoneInfo.ToSerializedString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.TimeZoneInfo.ToSerializedString) can be used across platforms to exhibit the same behavior:

```
# Note: The string was obtained *on Windows* as follows:
#   [System.TimeZoneInfo]::FindSystemTimeZoneById(
#     'Central Europe Standard Time'
#    ).ToSerializedString()
$tz = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::FromSerializedString(
  'Central Europe Standard Time;60;(UTC+01:00) Belgrade, Bratislava, Budapest, Ljubljana, Prague;Central Europe Standard Time;Central Europe Daylight Time;[01:01:0001;12:31:9999;60;[0;02:00:00;3;5;0;];[0;03:00:00;10;5;0;];];'
)

# Convert the current local date to the target time zone.
[System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTime(
  (Get-Date), # better: [datetimeoffset]::now
  $tz
)
```

Note:

- The reason that using a `[datetimeoffset]` ([`System.DateTimeOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTimeOffset)) instance as input is preferable is that the `ConvertTime()` call returns a `[datetimeoffset]` instance too, which is an *unambiguous, fully specified* point in time, based on the applicable UTC offset value being built into the value.
- By contrast, a `[datetime]` ([`System.DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime)) instance as input causes `ConvertTime()` to return a `[datetime]` instance whose `.Kind` property value is `Unspecified`. That is, it represents a *nominal* point in time that is only fully specified *if combined with external time-zone / UTC-offset information*.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the time like the following:

```
[System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTime((Get-Date),[System.TimeZoneInfo]::FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time"))
```

Comment: As I mentioned this string is different on different systems so it's not always available.

Answer (score 0):

To build on [Guenther's fine answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64067193/4749264) an alternative is to leverage the Get-TimeZone cmelet available in PowerShell 5+.

```
$Date      = Get-Date
$TimeZone  = Get-TimeZone -Id "W. Europe Standard Time"
$OtherDate = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTime( $Date, $TimeZone )
```

Get-TimeZone allows you to lookup a time zone by ID or name, and returns a TimeZoneInfo object same as the segment `[System.TimeZoneInfo]::FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time")` it's slightly more native though.

This is broken up a bit by variables, but it can be a one-liner just the same.

```
[System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTime( (Get-Date), (Get-TimeZone -Id "W. Europe Standard Time") )
```

These tested good in PowerShell 5.1 and 7.0

Comment: Marc's concern is that the time-zone identifiers aren't the same _across platforms_ and whether there are shorter names to refer to them. If you do know the name of the time zone, the `[System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId()` approach shown in the question itself is simpler and more efficient.